# Is there a better method of calling a comparision over a list of objects in C#?

Tags: c#, list, optimization, foreach, comparison

I am reading in lines from a large text file. Amongst these file are occasional strings, which are in a preset list of possibilities, and I wish to check the line currently being read for a match to any of the strings in the possibilities list. If there is a match I want to simply append them to a different list, and continue the loop I am using to read the file.

I was just wondering if there is a more efficent way to do a line.Contains() or equivilance check against say the first element in the list, then the second, etc. without using a nested loop or a long if statement filled with "or"s.

Example of what I have now:

```
List<string> possible = new List<string> {"Cat", "Dog"}
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(someFile))
{
  string aLine;
  while ((aLine = sr.Readline()) != null)
  {
    if (...)
    {
       foreach (string element in possible)
       {
         if line.Contains(element) == true
         {
          ~add to some other list
          continue
         }
       }
       ~other stuff
     }
   }
```

Comment: So if line contains any of those values, you want to add that line to your list?

Comment: using a `HashSet` for `possible` would yield better performance for larger collections.

Comment: The only way to make it more efficient is to make the parsing more efficient. For example, if you have "hi there" and "hi my friend" as part of your list, it would be good to check for "hi" only once... as far as I know, only compiled regular expressions do that... but doing better runtime performance... I have no idea where the cross over is. Otherwise the ".Any" reference below is pretty nice!

Comment: @Magnus He is checking if one string is contained in another.  A `HashSet` would only be useful for equality checking of strings.

Comment: @Servy The question states "I wish to check the line currently being read for a match to any of the strings in the possibilities list"

Comment: @Magnus Yes.  I'm aware of that.  In what way is putting the items in `possible` in a hashset going to improve your ability to determine if any of those strings is contained in the current line?  Even if they're in a `HashSet`, there's nothing to do but iterate them all and call `line.Contain` on each item.

Comment: For readability, I recommend replacing `using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(someFile)) {string aLine; while ((aLine = sr.Readline()) != null) {` with `foreach (string aLine in File.ReadLines(someFile)) {`. Note that `File.ReadLines`, like `StreamReader`, does not read the entire file at once.  Peeking at the source code, `File.ReadLines` is implemented as a `StreamReader` which reads lines individually...pretty much the same as your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for:

```
if(possible.Any(r=> line.Contains(r)))
{

}
```

Comment: So ? is this efficient ? inside of if statement you still need to find common elements and that requires another query or loop

Comment: @Selman22, it would be rougly equal to the pseudo-code OP has now, LINQ is just elegant :P

Comment: @Selman22: Efficiency is defined as value produced divided by resources consumed. Since we don't know what you value or what resources you care about, no one but you can measure efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about more efficient run-time wise, but you can eliminate a lot of code by using LINQ:

```
otherList.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(somefile).
    .Where(line => possible.Any(p => line.Contains(p)));
```

Comment: Still trying to get the hang of LINQ, but just looking here it seems this may be an issue for my means, as I need to break the file into five list all together in a specific order, this is only one case I need to watch for. Could LINQ provide more utility for a wider spread of cases then tackling just one with a similar line?

Comment: You can use `ReadLines` here instead of `ReadAllLines` to allow the data from the file to be streamed.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your work to **Get Data** and then **Analyse Data**. You don't have to do it in the same loop.

After reading lines, there are many ways to filter them. The most readable and maintenable IMO is to use Linq.

You can change your code to this:

```
// get lines
var lines = File.ReadLines("someFile");

// what I am looking for
var clues = new List<string> { "Cat", "Dog" };

// filter 1. Are there clues? This is if you only want to know
var haveCluesInLines = lines.Any(l => clues.Any(c => l.Contains(c)));

// filter 2. Get lines with clues
var linesWithClues = lines.Where(l => clues.Any(c => l.Contains(c)));
```

**Edit:**

Most likely you will have little clues and many lines. This example checks each line with every clue, saving time.